# Hibernate/JPA: Add/Remove child from collection on update() or saveOrUpdate() not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Task_Monitor_Header")
@SequenceGenerator(name="INC_TASK_HEADER",sequenceName="GEN_TMH_ID")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name="tmh_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="INC_TASK_HEADER")
    private Integer id = new Integer(0);

    @ManyToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name="task_equipment",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="equipment_id"))
    private Set<Equipment> equipments = new HashSet<Equipment>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="task", targetEntity = TaskCondition.class, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @OrderBy(value="seq")
    private Set<TaskCondition> conditions = new HashSet<TaskCondition>();
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Task_Monitor_Items")
@SequenceGenerator(name="INC_TASK_ITEMS",sequenceName="GEN_TMI_ID")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TaskCondition {

    @Id
    @Column(name="tmi_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="INC_TASK_ITEMS")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tmi_task_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="conditions")
    private Task task;
...
}
```

And when I try add or remove a child from collection `conditions`, and call hibernate `save()` or `saveOrUpdate()` it doesn't change database state but, it works fine if I do the same on `equipments` (`@ManyToMany`) collection.

Eg.

```
public class TaskDaoImpl implements TaskDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public void edit(Task task, Authentication authentication) {

        //Retrieve first child of Set
        TaskCondition condition = task.getConditions().iterator().next();

        //Remove that child
        task.getConditions().remove(condition);

        //Update the whole thing
        session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(task);

    }
}
```

Could someone help me? I've already tried `@CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`, `orphanRemoval=true` without success.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're doing the save/saveOrUpdate?

Comment: Sure! 
(At)Autowired
private SessionFactory session;

(At)Override
public void edit(Task task, Authentication authentication) {
 session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(task);
}

Comment: I think if you could post some example code showing how you changed the collection and how you expected the database to change to your answer would be more helpful.

Comment: In fact I am receiving the object from a client, but I can simulate that here ;)

Just a second!

Comment: I guess your best shot to debug this is to make a simple `static main` style app and simulate the scenario. If you get to that, post the code and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for answer, I found the problem!

The problem is that Hibernate before deleting, updates the FK column setting it to `null` and in my database it was `NOT NULL`.

And changed it to **unidirectional** relationship

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="tmi_task_id", referencedColumnName = "tmh_id")
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Set<TaskCondition> conditions;
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is a bidirectional relationship, you have to remove the reference from both entities:

```
task.getConditions().remove(condition);
condition.setTask(null);
```

The same applies for create.

Comment: Hi Bruno, in my case I'm receiving the object as-is (without the child already) so, should I retrieve the database's version and iterate it for comparing with the new one? This sounds manual work. Isn't there any other 'smarter' way for hibernate doing that?

Comment: I think you need to do this if both are in memory, because hibernate will try to persist the context's state, and based on your edit the condition is attached and still references the task.

Comment: I tried to set relationship unidirectional, but didn't work also =//